# TrackballControls.js: this.domElement.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, three.js

I get this error from the TrackballControls.js:

```
this.domElement.addEventListener is not a function
```

This occurs when I assign the `TrackballControls` to a DOM:

```
// 'container' is a variable
var trackballControls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, container);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.  After hours of troubleshooting, it turned out to be inappropriate characters in the name and id of my DIV tag.  Once I changed it to all alphabetic characters it worked fine.

Comment: For me, the issue was not with name, I already used alphabets only. But the issue was my code was returning div as null.