# Getting this error "_this.dispatchEvent is not a function" using trackballcontrols.js but I doon't know why

Tags: three.js

Here is my code below. I followed  a tutorial, [tutorial link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_KkHLimetQ&t=615s) , to the "T" on how to use trackball.js however I am still getting an error. This is the only question on stackoverflow that is close to mine, [TrackballControls.js: this.domElement.addEventListener is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639686/trackballcontrols-js-this-domelement-addeventlistener-is-not-a-function) however his solution does not seem to be my solution. Here is a screenshot of the error, [screenshot](http://s24.postimg.org/9pqf2n3w5/screenshot_840.png).

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: #ffffff;
                margin: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r57/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="TrackballControls.js"></script>
        <script>

            var camera, controls, scene, renderer;

            init();
            animate();

            function init(){
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth/ window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
                camera.position.z = 500;

                controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
                controls.addEventListener('change', render );

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(100,100,100);
                var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
                scene.add(mesh);

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight)
                document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
            }

            function animate(){
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                controls.update();

            }

            function render(){

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: r57 is a very old version of three.js. Can you update to the newer one? Is `TrackballControls.js` you are using the same version?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that. That did the trick, I updated it to the most recent which I believe is r83 and now it works. Also I wasn't able to tell what version TrackBallControls is, it doesn't say.

Comment: if you pick up `TrackballControls.js` from the examples directory that comes with the release you should be fine.